# Google analytics API - how to add dashboard widget of "1 Day Active Users"?

Tags: google-analytics

I didn't find any way to add a dashboard widget that shows the info of "1 Day Active Users".
There is a way to do that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Its about using Google Analytics website and is not programing related.

Comment: Why it has to be related to programming? I am asking about the interface and how can I ask questions about the data...